# Finding $g'(x)$ if $f'(x)$ is given and $g$ is the inverse of $f$.

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

> If $g$ is the inverse of $f$ and $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x^3}$. Find $g'(x)$.

How to proceed with the question? I thought of integrating $f'(x)$ and then finding the inverse of $f$, i.e., $g$ and then differentiating it. 
But the answer is given as a function of $g(x)$ itself so I’m stuck there.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Note that $f(g(x))=x.$ Differentiate and use the Chain Rule.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: How did I get what? If you're asking how I got $f(g(x))=x,$ it's from a common definition of $g=f^{-1}.$ If you're asking something else, please clarify.

Comment: yup I was asking the same

Comment: Okay. Does my response clear things up for you at all?

Comment: still not clear

Comment: A very common definition can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function). Let me know if you have specific questions about said definition.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {d}{dx} f^{-1}(x) = \frac {1}{f'(y)}$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = {1 \over 1+x^3}$ and $y=f(x)$, then $x= \sqrt[3]{{1 \over y}-1}$.

$g'(x) = -{1 \over 3 x^2 (\sqrt[3]{{1 \over y}-1})^2 } = -{1 \over 3 x^2 g^2(x) }$.

Comment: I tried that but answer is given in the form of g(x)